# Webscraping Zillow in R, and finding Latitude and Longitude using Selector Gadget

Tags: r, web-scraping, latitude-longitude, zillow

I'm trying to webscrape latitude and longitude for Zillow houses using selector gadget tool for R, using rvest and dplyr packages.

Im trying find the latitude and longitude for each  listing and store it into the data frame I created using the following code. This what I have now. Can anyone help?

```
link = "https://www.zillow.com/arlington-va/2_p/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22arlington%2C%20virginia%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-77.46492611914063%2C%22east%22%3A-76.73708188085938%2C%22south%22%3A38.64364888623124%2C%22north%22%3A39.117234332841704%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A30258%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D"


page = read_html(link)

bed =  page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-details li:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
bed =  page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-details li:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
bath = page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-details li:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
sqfoot = page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-details li:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
price = page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-price") %>% html_text()
marketime= page %>% html_nodes(".list-card-variable-text") %>% html_text()

houses = data.frame(address, bed, bath, sqfoot, price, marketime) %>%
mutate(bed = as.numeric(substring(bed, 1, 1)), bath = substring(bath, 1, 1), sqfoot = 
gsub(",","",sqfoot), price = gsub(",", "", price))

houses <- mutate(houses, sqfoot = as.numeric(gsub(" sqft", "", houses$sqfoot)), price = 
as.numeric(substring(price, 2, nchar(houses$price))))
```

Comment: Where is latitude and longitude information on that page?

Comment: I do not think I am able to use inspectorGadget to pull lat/longitude

Comment: However if you inspect page, and use control F(ind) in source code, latitude and longitude are assigned to every listing. I just dont know how to extract them and store them in frame

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all the listing info from script tags on the page (though I think zillow does an API which would be a better source)

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

page <- read_html('https://www.zillow.com/arlington-va/2_p/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%22currentPage%22%3A2%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22arlington%2C%20virginia%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-77.64070736914063%2C%22east%22%3A-76.56130063085938%2C%22south%22%3A38.56616517053261%2C%22north%22%3A39.19411978197601%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A30258%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D')

data <- page %>% html_nodes('.photo-cards script') %>%  html_text() 
info <- map(data, ~jsonlite::parse_json(., simplifyVector = T))
mask <- map(info, ~ 'geo' %in% names(.) ) %>% unlist() 
info <- info[mask] # filter for only those with lat/lon in geo

df <- map_df(info, ~ {
  data.frame(
    Name = .$name,
    Latitude <- .$geo$latitude,
    Longitude = .$geo$longitude,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )
})
```